# Should we sign up for Winter Bash 2013?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winterbash, fun

Is Winter Bash happening in Code Review? Many beta sites are going to participate in Winter Bash ([AV.SE](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/do-we-want-to-participate-in-winter-bash-2013-gravatar-hats) and [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/do-we-want-to-join-in-the-winter-bash-again?cb=1) site's moderators are receiving email from Stack Exchange).  Have any of CR's moderators received such email?

In my opinion, participating in such events may help us graduate.

- [Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)
- [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [List of hats to earn](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/)
- [**Wrap-Up**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)

Comment: Ts, winter. It's 24 degrees (celsius) and going strong into summer here. You guys just live in a weird part of the world ;)

Answer (score 13):

## Me wants. Sign us up NOW!

We need hatz. Winter is cold and boring.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the moderators have received this email.  We are also the ones who must sign this site up for Winter Bash, but *only* if the collective community opts in.  In addition, individual users who don't want to participate can opt out.  This event is entirely optional for everyone.

<s>So, please give your vote to help us decide on this.  The deadline for signing up is **December 1st**.</s>

**UPDATE:** We are now signed up!  This will begin on **16 December 2013** and end on **3 January 2014**.

Comment: [Sounds like fun](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) - where do we sign?

Comment: My question is not constructive since I don't know much more. @Jamal as you are a moderator and also a good speaker, you will know much more than I do. So can you please come up with your own question/discussion on Winter-Bash? that would be great.

Comment: @retailcoder: The moderators have to sign up.  We just ask the community if they want to participate.

Comment: @tintinmj: This is okay. :-) I've never participated before, so even I cannot say much.  It doesn't need to be super official; it just needs to get the word out.

Comment: I don't see why not. Go ahead and sign us up.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: I'll wait about a day or so.  Hopefully this question will soon appear on the Community Bulletin.

Comment: Not fair, I had already upvoted this answer...

Answer (score 5):

### 16<sup>th</sup> DECEMBER

> ### Before WinterBash
>
> [image]

---

> ### During WinterBash
>
> [image]

---

> ### After Winterbash
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>Bob is sad, he lovz hat!</sub>

Comment: -1 Spongebob is hatless.

Comment: @Jamal bob will get a hat after 16th ;)

Comment: Ugh. This is why we need meta-bounties!

Comment: @retailcoder shall I take this as compliment?

Comment: Totally! That's excellent!