# CR Weekend Challenge

Tags: discussion, fun, weekend-challenge

Those of you that weren't following what's going on in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/code-review-general-room) might have been taken by surprise by a recent avalanche of ***Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock*** posts.

This is how it started:

> *OK, weekend challenge.... we all solve the Rock Paper Scissors Lizzard Spock problem with our 'favourite' language, and we all have to post a question here with our solution to be reviewed.*
>
> http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12408541#12408541

If this is a *good* idea, then I think we have something like an *amazing* idea waiting to be exploited: Each weekend challenge can be discussed in one of our lovely chat rooms, normally [The 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

The per-round output [zombie-hunting mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission) is slowing down; until [Winter Bash 2013](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/should-we-sign-up-for-winter-bash-2013) starts, there's still a couple of weeks. Just because it's fun, I suggest we create a [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) tag that people could follow (or ignore), and for the next couple weeks, we decide on a little project to submit review requests for.

---

#### Rules

- The project must be a small (tiny!) project that can be completed within a couple of hours.
- There is no language constraint, participants can implement the project in any language they like.
- The project scope should be vague enough for participants to implement it as ["simply" | "cleverly crafted"] as they can/like; the only constraint is that the project must solve the given problem.
- Avoid the [get-it-done-fast trap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12527795#12527795), and post your best possible code! <s>This isn't a race for the first post</s> **We want quality posts!**
- If you are late in submitting your solution, <s>we will hunt you down and</s> **That's perfectly OK**. We really can't prevent anyone from submitting code to any solution. Just because it's not the "active weekly challenge" doesn't make it off-topic, as long as you write a question that [fits what the site is about](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about).
- Entries must be tagged with [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge), along with the tag of the language you're coding your weekend challenge entry with (, and any other applicable tags).

---

#### How it works

Each week a new meta-question will be posted on this site; the community submits ideas as answers to that question (1 idea per answer), and the highest upvoted answer on the Saturday (12AM UTC) of that week, becomes that weekend's challenge.

Each week the meta-question containing the proposals, will be posted here as an answer, with a link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I see it, these weekend challenges are a really good thing. Not only does it show that Code Review is an active community, it is also a great opportunity to learn something new.

There are so many ways to do the same thing in programming. Not only is there many different programming languages, but there is also [very](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-as-a-code-style-and-challenge) big [differences](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36412/another-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-implementation) of how to do things within the same programming language.

Maybe these challenges can also be a way to learn how to write better code in a [language you are not normally using](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cobol)

Answer (score 6):

## Weekend Challenge #3

Proposals here: [Weekend Challenge #3](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/weekend-challenge-3)

---

Winning proposal:

#### Sudoku Solver (9 votes)

Entries can be submitted as of 2013-12-14.

Please tag submissions with [sudoku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) and [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge).

Answer (score 4):

## Weekend Challenge #2

Proposals here: [Weekend Challenge #2](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/weekend-challenge-2)

---

Winning proposal:

#### Poker Hand Evaluation (6 votes)

Entries can be submitted as of 2013-12-07.

Answer (score 3):

## Weekend Challenge #4

Proposals here: [Weekend Challenge #4](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/weekend-challenge-4)

---

Winning proposal:

#### Gotta catch'em all! (5 votes)

Entries can be submitted as of 2013-12-21.

Please tag submissions with [json](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json) and [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge).

Answer (score 2):

## Weekend Challenge #5

This one is a little special. Let's give it a Holiday-ish twist :)

Proposals here: [Weekend Challenge #5](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/weekend-challenge-5)

---

Winning proposal:

#### A Simple Text Adventure (7 votes)

Entries can be submitted as of 2013-12-28.

Please tag submissions with [console](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console), [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) and [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge).

Answer (score 2):

## Weekend Challenge #6

Proposals here: [Weekend Challenge #6](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/weekend-challenge-6)

---

Winning proposal:

**Create a scheduler (2 votes)**

---

Given the low participation (Holidays?), [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) will take a break. I wasn't even expecting it to last this long! In the mean time, feel free to submit entries for any submitted proposals on any challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## February 2014 Challenge

[Weekend-Challenge Reboot](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/weekend-challenge-reboot)

After a 1-month break, let's reboot the thing as a monthly challenge.