# Weekend Challenge #4

Tags: discussion, fun, weekend-challenge

One single proposal per answer, most upvoted as of 2013-12-21 (12:00AM UTC) becomes our next challenge!

The winning entry shall be marked as the accepted answer.

<sub>[index](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/cr-weekend-challenge) | [previous challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1245/23788) | [next challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/weekend-challenge-5)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Gotta catch'em all!

Write a small program that will send an HTTP GET request to the [Pokédex](http://pokeapi.co/docs/#pokedex), **find all Pokémons** and deserialize them into objects, optionally displaying them along with some relevant information.

The [author of the web API](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33459/phalt) has created a CR account just for this! See comment [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/beginners-java-project-basic-pokedex-using-if-else-statements-suggestions/37243#comment61628_37243).

Comment: Oh wow! This is awesome, if my API is picked, I'll be happy to help judge the challenge and provide support :)

Comment: I think this needs something else to make it interesting. I mean, as it stands it looks as though `json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokedex/1/'))` would be a valid solution. Something like, "fetch two Pokémons and simulate a battle"? (I know nothing about Pokémon but I believe they fight battles according to some kind of rules, right?)

Comment: That's a good idea, I like that. Maybe some form of "Top Trumps" with Pokemon statistics? How about - grab 2 random pokemon and compare their stats and determine the winner?

Answer (score 2):

### [Internet Bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot)

The challenge is to program an [Internet Relay Chat bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat_bot):

> An IRC bot is a set of scripts or an independent program that connects
>   to Internet Relay Chat as a client, and so appears to other IRC users
>   as another user. An IRC bot differs from a regular client in that
>   instead of providing interactive access to IRC for a human user, it
>   performs automated functions.

You could also deviate from this and create an automated bot to respond to certain messages in the [Code Review chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) or any other SE site chat<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Take a look at [what StackExchange tolerates](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1292/27623) if you choose to go down this route.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207131/what-should-be-the-limits-for-chat-bots-interacting-with-regular-users), [another related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-i-please-be-trusted-to-not-to-script-a-bot-that-dumps-an-endless-stream-of-s), and [one more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196758/what-interactions-between-a-bot-and-the-chat-system-are-allowed)

Answer (score 2):

#### Decrypt a monoalphabetic substitution cipher

A [monoalphabetic substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher#Simple_substitution) applies a substitution table to the letters in the plaintext (often omitting all non-letters to disguise the word boundaries). For example, if the table is:

```
plaintext   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ciphertext  RDYBXZWFCTIELAMJPGQVNSOHUK
```

Then the plaintext `HELLO WORLD` would be encrypted as `FXEEMOMGEB`.

Your program should take as input a ciphertext, for example:

```
UXLIRNXSOPQAKJBJTXSVTJKRHXKKJKLIQQOEBLXRSNJKWQKQKYSAQKLRVQNLJKQD 
QRPLJRSEWIRSWQWJHQKTRKKQRWIXSODXNXJSNJTLIQBRNLLIXNXNUIRLXYSAQKLR
VQLJAJTJKEJYKQRAQK
```

(together with advice from the cryptanalyst, if you wish) and output the plaintext.

Some more examples to test your code on (each is encrypted with a different cipher):

```
EVSXTTIWGVRMWIXWDXEMHWXDVCWGVSIKXWIRIQIVQFIVUUFIKGXEMLFVVMRVCFMW
XTGIWFBZITGIWITGXEBEXEDVTGIWYVCETWDLIBTIZIWKVLIXCTBUCFTGIWIBKEVQ
FXYIFBOIGVSI

UZIRUKEJJXVMDKADJZXRYHSNOZENDNDKZXJDUIDJHJUAOAYIDUZIEUZNUKKXVOUA
OXZKUSSTSDUKYJUGSDUZIHDZOUSEUIDMOKCUVDAMDXGBDVAOGDKASOLDIAXKDD

EPOMQDHHXOHXKMOPKTQPNXTPEUCHKSDTUXDQDMDSDHNDQDOKMDQDMKXKQEADWYPK
TPGNKAPRQXNXOTLWKQOCPEDKOTGXVVXTHPOHSPWHXXTLWXGPOHSXNXKQQXWAGXHN
DOGXHEDHHKRQXH

CYNCWRBNQNGNYPQANYPJQRCRBNCRBNSFYLQCCWRBNQNIBPXBPQRBNYFRJSFKGFYF
YLIBPXBRBNQHPSPRIBCLNXPHBNSQRBNG
```

<sub>(submitted by [Gareth Rees](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees))</sub>

Comment: Can we assume that the plaintext is in English?

Comment: If you like! Guesses about the nature of the plaintext come under the heading of "advice from the cryptanalyst".

Answer (score 0):

### [StackExchange App](https://stackapps.com/)

This is more of an open-end challenge to develop any app that does something on the Stack Exchange network.  It could be anything a tack-able chat box to a app that triggers a desktop notification every time there is an event associated with your account.

Use the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get you started.