# Weekend Challenge #5

Tags: discussion, fun, weekend-challenge

One single proposal per answer, most upvoted as of 2013-12-28 (12:00AM UTC) becomes our next challenge!

The winning entry shall be marked as the accepted answer.

---

This one is a little special. Let's give it a Holiday-ish twist :)

<sub>[index](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/cr-weekend-challenge) | [previous challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/weekend-challenge-4) | [next challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/weekend-challenge-6)</sub>

Comment: Nooo! I was hoping there would be a Christmas break for this, I can't participate this week!

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg you can always submit a late entry ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

### A simple text adventure?

Something along the lines of [zork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork)?

Basically a short prewritten story with a few actions to manoeuvre around it, along the lines of:

> You enter the elevator there are three floors which floored you pick?

- Basement
- First Floor
- Penthouse

> go to **Penthouse**

---

I would say given the season make it a Christmas story and keep it as console line writing for simplicity.

Thoughts?

Comment: I like that. Write a short story, use your wit-pen, make it funny and xmas-y. And yeah, shows us *the mother of console text games*.

Answer (score 2):

[Hunt the Grinch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus),

Either play through command line or simple UI.
The map should be either

- a [regular grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRegular_grid.svg)
- an [icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) for extra awesomeness

This challenge would require some [d20](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/20-sided_dice_250.jpg) gazing, possibly some scratching on paper combined with deep thoughts on how to best capture the dungeon elegantly.

The following mapping gives the xmas twist:

- Wumpus -> Grinch
- Agent -> A little kid
- Bats -> Reindeer