# Weekend Challenge #6

Tags: discussion, fun, weekend-challenge

One single proposal per answer, most upvoted as of 2014-01-04 (12:00AM UTC) becomes our next challenge!

The winning entry shall be marked as the accepted answer.

> Oddly the system is starting to think these posts are dupes - *This post appears to be a duplicate of Weekend Challenge #5*. This text beats the dupe-detection.

---

<sub>[index](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/cr-weekend-challenge) | [previous challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/weekend-challenge-5) | next challenge</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a scheduler

We all have busy lives, and a schedule would be really helpful in sorting it all out.

The basic idea for this challenge is to create a program that has a calendar, in which you can create events.  These events can be all day events, or can happen only in a certain time frame.  The program probably should also alert the user when an event is coming up.

Comment: Something like Google Calendar or what? Elaborate, please.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Is that good?