# How should really big code challenge submissions be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-length, community-challenge

As far as I am aware, a question consisting of a really big codebase is generally off-topic here, as our answerers are simply not able to put so much effort in it.

I'd like to talk about a special case here though, questions that are posted as a result of a Code Challenge, more specifically this case will be about [this submission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1608/32231).

Out of personal experience, I am working on my own implementation for about two weeks already (found [here](https://github.com/skiwi2/TCG)), and it is currently on 3K loc and guessing 40 at about 40 files. I can imagine my final implementation nearing 10K loc and at least 100 files.

What is the process I should use for getting this code reviewed? It being such a large project, it does consist out of several modules.

Comment: My code for this is also huge, I will be asking for a review on it module-per-module. Thank goodness I don't have so much spaghetti code (I think) so it is possible to separate my questions in a quite good way. As long as a question fits on 30K lines, there's no limit to how much code you have in the question. (I've been very close to that limit before, one time actually [exceeded it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36916/weekend-challenge-poker-hand-evaluation))

Answer (score 3):

Business as usual: break it down into as many smaller posts as needed to make it digestible.

..and [code-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) should be renamed [review-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-challenge) ;)

Comment: And then when I'm done breaking down the code and asking for individual reviews, I could ask about the breakdown structure as a question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @skiwi I think you could ask about the breakdown structure here as well. Not sure if it would be on-topic at programmers.