# Can I use posted programs as inspiration?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, etiquette

I often am stumped for ideas of what I want to try making next with my tiny Python vocabulary. Most things I think of are either too big or I'm not sure where to start, and so Code Review seems like a great place to browse for ideas of what to try next.

Is there anything wrong with recreating programs (usually in a different language than the original) that have been posted on Code Review to exercise and expand my knowledge in a language?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course you may!  That is, after all, the point of Creative Commons licensing — that you are free to learn from others' work and remix content into your own creations.  If it's a close derivative work, be sure to abide by the [terms of the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  If your work is just loosely inspired by something you saw, then attribution probably isn't required, but use your own discretion as to whether it would be appropriate to credit the source.

Answer (score -5):

the code here is like open-source almost, except we don't want you changing or code,  we don't post it unless we are ready for other people to use it.  we would appreciate some sort of link somewhere in the code giving us some credit, but it is not mandatory.

We often have Code Challenges,  you can look through some of our old code Challenges, some of them are fairly simple.

Check it out here:

[CR Weekend Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1201/18427)

Comment: I know what you mean to say, but ["shareware"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareware) is not the right word.

Comment: That's not what the license says: CC BY-SA means that attribution *is* mandatory, but on the other hand, anyone does have the right to modify the code (as long as the modified code is under the same license).