# What should be Meta's master community challenge tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

We currently have two Meta tags regarding community challenges:

- [weekend-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) (8 questions)
- [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge) (1 question)

The main site equivalent of these tags are also synonymized, which will eventually be done here as well.  However, does it make sense to also synonymize them with a new Meta tag called [community-challenge](/questions/tagged/community-challenge), which is also a main site tag?  The advantage here, though, is that no one can misuse the tags since programming questions don't exist here.  But it just seems odd to have the exact same set of tags.

What do you think?

**Note:** The [contest](/questions/tagged/contest) tag doesn't apply here.  That tag is only for general site challenges, not regular community programming challenges.

Comment: Someone needs to throw together a matrix of what terms have been used, and where.

Comment: Code Challenge sounds an awful lot like main site's Programming Challenge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It started with [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge), in [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1201/23788) (the *rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock* challenge). Then it was used pretty much every week of December 2013 when a new meta post came up for voting on what the next challenge should be.

Then we "rebooted" the thing after taking a break, and since it no longer was *over-the-weekend* we came up with [code-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

[community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) came after, to rule them all.

---

The master tag can only be the more generic [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) tag, in my opinion. *It was created for that purpose*.

Comment: Thank you for the history lesson (reminder). Yes, that's the progression, and all those posts on the main site should be synonymized to [tag:community-challenge].