# Should we sign up for Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fun, winterbash

Winter Bash 2014 is approaching!  [We signed up for it last year](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/should-we-sign-up-for-winter-bash-2013), and it was a really big hit.  I'm still posting this in order to get an official word from the community and to make new users aware of this event.

Since the moderators have just received the announcement, there isn't much new info yet in terms of new 2014 sites.  Not too much should change, so feel free to look on last year's post for more info.

However, we have some important dates:

- All sites (via a moderator) needs to submit their decision by **December 1st**.
- This event will run from **December 15th** to **January 4th**.

We were the top beta site on the leaderboards last year.  Although we have already graduated, we can still beat the other beta sites again (maybe even the graduated sites while we're at it)!

[image]

Comment: Well, duh, no-brainer... ok, you're a sponge, you are a no-brainer ;-)

Comment: At least it's opt-OUT this year instead of opt-IN. I'm not even sure if we need to post one one SQA since I know it will be a unanimous yes.

Comment: @corsiKa: The latest email tells us that it's opt-in this year.  I know that it would be an unanimous yes, but this at least informs new users and gets the hype going.

Comment: You might want to read it again. The latest email I have states: `All responses will need to be in by 1 December 2014. Sites that haven’t responded by then will be considered to have opted in to the event. (N.B: Last year the default was was opt out. This year you need to contact us if you don’t want to be involved.)`

Comment: @corsiKa: I thought that's what I've just said, or is it referring to something else?

Comment: You've got your definitions mixed up. If the program is `opt-X` then the default option is `not-X`. So an opt-in means the default is you sit out. That was last year. This year it's opt-out, meaning the default means you're in. =) #clarityishard

Comment: Sorry to be a complete idiot here, but what exactly is Winter Bash?

Comment: @EthanBierlein: It's basically an event involving completing tasks (similar to badges) in order to unlock temporary hats for your avatar.  You can view the links on [last year's post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/should-we-sign-up-for-winter-bash-2013).

Answer (score 19):

Yes.  I think it's absolutely fantastic.

Also, we need to propose this as a hat:
[image]

Comment: Did you miss [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213211/197901)?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Nice! I'm going to wait until after work to read that thread in depth.  Otherwise I'll have a lot more time to find hats...

Answer (score 17):

## YES. I want a hat!

[Obligatory text to reach the minimum answer length.]

Comment: You're already wearing a hat.

Comment: But I need a *new Winterbash hat*.

Comment: A hat in a hat... hatception...

Answer (score 17):

Do we ***really*** need to ask?

## Of course we should!!

[image]

Answer (score 15):

## On the plus side...

It will be a massive boost on the fun level. Gamification on steroids.

## On the negative side...

Uhm, is there a negative side? No, there isn't, BRING IT ON!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think hats are stupid and do not want my auto-generated avatar to have one. However, last year's [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq) explains hat you can get rid of them with a click. Assuming that is still valid, I vote **for** signing up since that allows everyone to chose for themselves whereas not participating excludes the silly hat lovers for no reason.

Comment: That's actually the best answer to this hype I've seen so far.