# Should we sign up for Winter Bash 2015?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fun, winterbash

Winter Bash 2015 is approaching! We signed up for it [last year](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/should-we-sign-up-for-winter-bash-2014), and it was a really big hit. We all had a lot of fun earning and showing our hats to the rest of the world.

Now after we have graduated we are in a greater field of competitioners and it will be hard to climb on the leaderboard to the 1st place, but we should really try to.

For everybody who is interested take a look at this very cool countdown which counts the minutes left [Winterbash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/).

The event seems to start on 14th of december, at least if my math hadn't lost me.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the mod email that was just sent out, no further action is necessary for opting in for Winter Bash this year:

> If you want in, you don't need to do anything; that's the default this year, due to overwhelming positive response in previous years.

Also, the event will run from **December 14th** to **January 3rd**.

Answer (score 16):

[ho-ho-ho](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ho-ho-ho)

Yes, I think we definitely should. It encourages participation and might get some of our more inactive reviewers (myself included) to do more reviews :-)

Answer (score 9):

## YES! Because ***HATS***!

Oh, and also because we like Fun™ around here.

Answer (score 6):

## On the plus side...

A massive boost on the fun level. Gamification on steroids.

## On the negative side...

Uhm, is there a negative side? No there isn't, BRING ON THEM HATS!

Answer (score 5):

### Uhm... premature?

Do you know something that the rest of us don't? Are you sure that we need to "sign up"?

My expectation is that WinterBash is now a "default" thing, and that individuals get to opt-out if they don't want to see it.

So, is there some place where there's an announcement, or are you just guessing?

Comment: No announcement just found the countdown. About the "sign up"  I just copied that part from last years question.

Comment: Sites do also get the option to opt out, if they want.